# VS Code Autosave cursor jump

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

(I've looked for examples of this all over SO and the VS Code github, in every case the resolution was to disable extensions, I have no extensions installed.)

I've been working in a Remote Container in VS Code 1.66.2 for quite a while.  Today out of nowhere, whenever the autosave happens when I'm working on Jupyter Notebook, the cursor jumps out of the cell and if I start typing it is now in command mode.  I have deleted all the extensions in my local directory (and in the container), removed all the files in the extension-cache (both locally and in the container OS).  Still unable to find the autosave bug.  Is there a registry setting that I'm missing or files stored someone that I'm not seeing?  I've also uninstalled/reinstalled VS Code.

[image: Gif of editting and cursor jump behavior]

Comment: I have faced the very same issue and it then expanded further. So, when I am typing in a cell the cursor jumps out of the cell which is very annoying. It might also cause unwanted deletion while you are typing. I did uninstall the VS Code and Python and tried even older/newer versions but it didn't fix the issue. I asked our IT to replace my laptop. I haven't had any issues on the new laptop. Still can't wrap my head around the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same thing. I disabled all extensions, and the problem still existed.

My problem was that I was working on a jupyter notebook in a network location. Once I copied the file to my local drive and worked on it, I no longer had the issue. This may not solve your problem directly given that you are working in a remote container, but someone else might find this useful.